# Qt QInputDialog parameter list

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, kde-plasma

I am starting a Qt course this semester. Having looked at the official documentation as well as some on line examples I am confused by the parameter lists of the QInputDialog and QMessagebox classes.

Is there anywhere where one could find some decent info as to what to pass when creating the class / form?

Right now I have this by trial error

```
tempC = QInputDialog::getDouble(0, "Temperature Converter",
                                "Enter the temperature in Celsius to convert to Fahrenheit:", 1);
```

Looking at the official docs doesn't help a lot either (at least not for me yet) as it says this:

```
double d = QInputDialog::getDouble(this, tr("QInputDialog::getDouble()"),
                                   tr("Amount:"), 37.56, -10000, 10000, 2, &ok);
```

as an example.

Any links will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you don't understand in [the docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qinputdialog.html#getDouble)? _Each_ parameter is explained in plain text.

Comment: Often, the first parameter is the MainWindow of your project.  The dialog will center itself relative to the given window.  The other parameters are clearly explained as Mat says.  What is the issue?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the correct documentation. I was using this:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qinputdialog.html

which contains much less info compared to this:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qinputdialog.html

Weird, Google returned the first link on my search and I assumed it was the only official docs available for the class...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
double d = QInputDialog::getDouble(this, tr("QInputDialog::getDouble()"),
                                   tr("Amount:"), 37.56, -10000, 10000, 2, &ok);
```

- A dialog will popup with parent the widget in which you are using this function. (`this`)
- The dialog's title will be  `QInputDialog::getDouble()` (`tr` is used in order to translate this string if you want using QtLinguist)
- Inside the dialog will be a double spibox and a label
- The label's string will be `Amount:`
- The default value of the spinbox (what you see when the dialog popups) will be `37.56`
- The minimum value will be `-10000` (you will not be able to set a value less than this)
- The maximum value will be `10000` (you will not be able to set a value greater than this)
- Two decimal point will be displayed, eg 3.478 will be displayed as 3.48.
- If the user presses the Ok button then the `ok` argument will be set to `true`, otherwise it will be set to `false`

Check the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qinputdialog.html#getDouble) which includes an example for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Much appreciated.